# Android: Resizing DatePicker still uses much space

Tags: android, resize, datepicker, size

my question is the following:
When I resize the DatePicker component using ScaleX and ScaleY (I make it smaller), it resizes correctly, but the widget still uses the same amount of space it used before. This means there are now extra spaces between the Picker and the other Views which look ugly...
Is there a way to make these extra spaces gone?

Ps. I know about the DatePicker dialoges. But they are not an option in my case.

Thanks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg5small"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/addNewEntry"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleX="0.9"
        android:scaleY="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/border2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/INR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextMin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/save"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/save" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml layout code.

Answer (score 0):

I have read befor that Number Pickers cannot be resized The issue is that you are trying to change the `android:orientation attribute`
if you want it costumized for your needs... youll have to implement it yourself im afraid